# Why is MAMP so slow to apply any change on my local dev sites?

Tags: mamp

I'm using MAMP (free version) to develop a website locally and it takes about 1 minute to apply any change (for instance, variable declaration). It takes the same time on Firefox, Safari or Chrome even if I load the page without the cache (CMD+SHIFT+R or SHIFT+refresh). Working with the "localhost/" url instead of a virtualhost doesn't change anything…

Does anybody have the same issue and have a solution?

Answer (score -3):

To fix it try this: in your hosts file you need to list all your local dev sites in a space delimited row like so...

127.0.0.1 localhost localsite1.dev localsite2.dev localsite3.dev

Comment: Hi Andreas. Thank you for your reply. I tried your tip (here is my modified host file in hidden folder named etc :
127.0.0.1 localhost dev.monsite.com
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost) but it doesn't make the trick…